# Is there a way to add Seven segment digit recognition is Android ML kit through fire base?

Tags: android, ocr, firebase-mlkit

I am building an Android app where seven segment digits need to be recognized from picture and populate on screen post processing the data.

This needs to happen in an offline mode. So it needs to run on mobile

I have looked at Tess but it makes app size considerably large hence would like to stick to ML Kit on Firebase.

Is there a way to add seven segment digit recognition in an existing ML Kit text vision API?

Answer (score 5):

*Is there a way to add seven segment digit recognition in an existing ML Kit text vision API?*

You cannot add it directly. We will have to update the model for the text recognition. That said, things like Driver licenses work for Text recognition with ML Kit. Have you tried running the [quick-starter sample app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit) or the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-android/#0) on your use case? If your use case does not work out, please feel free to reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) and we will be happy to understand your use case and update the model.

Other option to consider is training and [using your own custom model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/use-custom-models) in ML Kit. You could look at [TF Hub](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/) for doing transfer learning rather than training from scratch.

Comment: Tried the sample provided on CodeLab for my use case and it didn’t work. It doesn’t recognize seven segment numbers. Will reach out to Firebase support for this and update if we find any solution to this.

Comment: Thanks Taral. Kindly do. In the mean time, I have created an internal ticket for the modeling team to take a look at these kind of images. If you have a specific dataset, some samples from that will be handy.

Comment: I am also looking for the same solution. Read text from 7 segment images in my android app.